# OpenSSL and ARM optimizations for Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c++, c, openssl, arm, uwp

I'm porting VoIP application from iOS to UWP. Application makes heavily usage of OpenSSL encryption routines. I see for ARM based phones OpenSSL runs slowly sometimes.

I've checked OpenSSL distributions from Microsoft's github repository - but I do not see any ARM specific optimizations in source code for UWP.

Did anyone see such optimizations for ARM and UWP?

Comment: Did you read the generated code, perhaps the compiler itself is able to do "ARM-specific optimizations"? Also, this question isn't very well-suited for this site.

Comment: @unwind - I think you are right in the general case: *"question like this aren't very well-suited for this site [sic]"*. In this case, I think it should stay open. The reason why is a confluence of OpenSSL configuration and build settings; and Microsoft removing critical APIs, like the C-socket API. (This is speaking from experience when trying to perform the port to WIndows Phone, Windows Store and Windows UWP).